# Postgresql Altering Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to alter a table to add a new column and make that column a foreign key to another table in a single command in Postgresql? "alter table x add column y id references z(id)" doesn't seem to work as I had hoped.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it. What is "y id"?
May be

```
alter table x add column y int references z(id)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...
ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...
COMMIT
```

You can't convince me it's not a single command :).